# Stop angular cli asking for collecting analytics when I use ng build

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Angluar CLI is asking the following question when I am trying to build and deploy my project using gitlab CI/CD:

```html
> @angular/cli@8.0.0 postinstall /workspace/node_modules/@angular/cli
> node ./bin/postinstall/script.js

? Would you like to share anonymous usage data with the Angular Team at Google u
nder
Google’s Privacy Policy at https://policies.google.com/privacy? For more details
 and
how to change this setting, see http://angular.io/analytics. (y/N)
```

Of course I cannot input anything in the CI/CD pipeline. How can I can prevent angular cli from asking this question?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I had the same problem: The new analytics feature of Angular CLI was blocking my CI: https://travis-ci.org/LVM-IT/lvo-logging-lib. 
Solution: set the environent variable NG_CLI_ANALYTICS equal to ci

```
export NG_CLI_ANALYTICS=ci
```

see: https://github.com/LVM-IT/lvo-logging-lib/blob/329d014aa34dea49522f036e8d0b3aa3f71e33e7/.travis.yml#L16

[Link to ng-cli Analytics](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/design/analytics.md)

Comment: You can add this link to your answer: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/design/analytics.md

Comment: Where do you set NG_CLI_ANALYTICS ?

Comment: you can set it in your shell before runnung cli with export NG_CLI_ANALYTICS=ci. Here is an example for setting it on a Travis Build https://github.com/LVM-IT/lvo-logging-lib/blob/329d014aa34dea49522f036e8d0b3aa3f71e33e7/.travis.yml#L16

Comment: Done this. The env vars in Circle CI build logs saying: `Using environment variables from project settings and/or contexts
  CIRCLE_JOB=**REDACTED**
  NG_CLI_ANALYTICS=**REDACTED**`. Yet, the ng still requests for input

Comment: @Rexford: so there is a Problem with your circle ci configuration or with circle ci itself. As demonstrated above it works on Travis CI. follow the link for a configuration example for travis: https://github.com/LVM-IT/lvo-logging-lib/blob/329d014aa34dea49522f036e8d0b3aa3f71e33e7/.travis.yml#L16

Comment: What if it pops up for me locally and I want to disable it completely, without making changes to my repository?

Comment: Add `NG_CLI_ANALYTICS=false` to `/etc/environment` on Linux, to set it globally.

Answer (score 60):

Add following property to `angular.json` file:

```
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  }
```

Comment: WebStorm gives me a warning saying "Property 'analytics' is not allowed", with the quick fix being "Remove prohibited property 'analytics'"

Comment: Thank you! Not all of us want everything to be global and bound to a machine instead of a project (and some of us just use notepad)! This goes right at the top level inside the first paren set: https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config

Answer (score 29):

I used the command,

`ng analytics off`

and the prompt was not shown again.

Reference: https://angular.io/analytics#disabling-usage-analytics

Comment: This doesn't work cause running this command actually causes the question for me.

Comment: Don't know why this answer get downvoted but it worked for me.

Comment: upvoted. It would work for you have access in the environment(e.g local). You can use the answer if you want it to turn off globally. @ChipAllen I think you run the command inside your project. You can run it outside the angular projects to avoid prompting the question.

Comment: it worked for me. I wish I should have landed here earlier.

Comment: upvoted, agreed with @kenneth, as per official document execute command outside the project. https://angular.io/analytics

Comment: This should have been the answer.

Comment: If you have @ChipAllen 's problem and if this doesn't work for you, and it keeps prompting, try using ```ng analytics disable --global true```  in newer angular versions. Source: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56355499/stop-angular-cli-asking-for-collecting-analytics-when-i-use-ng-build)

Comment: Running `ng analytics off` pops the answer, then after you answer it, it will set up `angular.json` like @Palpatine1991 said in his answer.

Comment: `ng analytics off -g` for short to disable everywhere, cheers!

Answer (score 11):

To solve this, run the command appointing to `/dev/null`

```
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli > /dev/null
```

Comment: Make sure to explain why the proposed solution should work.

Comment: Neither of the other answers worked for me - but this one did - thanks!

Answer (score 8):

NG_CLI_ANALYTICS="false" is the correct env variable value

see linked comment;

"export NG_CLI_ANALYTICS=off didn't work for me, but export NG_CLI_ANALYTICS="false" does"

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/16784#issuecomment-637693422

Comment: Thanks. It really was annoying. I didn't want to commit any changes on that angular.json

Answer (score 5):

exporting the env variable didn't work for me... What did work was this

> echo N | ng analytics off

it didn't ask again afterwards

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me on my Dockerfile.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `export NG_CLI_ANALYTICS="false"` in bash,

or it is `ARG NG_CLI_ANALYTICS="false"` in Dockerfile.

Comment: For Dockerfile it should be `ENV NG_CLI_ANALYTICS="false"`

Answer (score 2):

For circle CI, this worked for me:

```
- run:
    environment:
      NG_CLI_ANALYTICS: "ci"
    command: npm install
```

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this by adding the environment variable in my machine by running this PowerShell command with Admin privilege.

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("NG_CLI_ANALYTICS", "false", "Machine")
```

Basically, there are 2 approaches to fix this.

1. Add `analytics: false` value in `angular.json` file which the prompt or `ng analytics off` command does automatically.
2. For me approach 1 was not feasible as updating project's `angular.json` file was not acceptable therefore I preferred to set environment variable `NG_CLI_ANALYTICS` variable as `false` in my machine. This is the cleanest approach and wouldn't affect other's environment.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone in a rush, it may be worthwhile clarifying that when you run `ng analytics off` or `ng analytics disable` *from the root of your Angular project*, the Angular CLI will add, on your behalf, the following to your angular.json:

```
 "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  }
```

So, you get to choose: you either run the CLI command or you add it manually to your angular.json. However, if you decide to use the CLI command,

1. verify that your angular.json was correctly updated and
2. commit those changes.

**Do not expect** the Angular CLI command to work as part of a deployment script on a remote server.

Answer (score 1):

Script circle CI to disable it, if the analytics prompt blocking the CI

```
 - run:
      name: 'Set env'
      command: echo 'export NG_CLI_ANALYTICS=ci' >> $BASH_ENV
```

Answer (score 0):

use this commond to off...##

```
ng analytics project off
```

it works....

Answer (score -2):

En angular.json, agregar al final o inicio:
`"cli": { "analytics": false }`

quedaria algo asi:

```js
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    ...
  },
  "defaultProject": "z",
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  }
}
```