# Circleci environment variable for Angular Ng analytics not working

Tags: angular-cli, circleci, circleci-2.0

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56360325/1757321), I've updated my project circle ci config file to include the environment variable specified.

And this shows up in the logs of CI when building:

```
Using environment variables from project settings and/or contexts
  CIRCLE_JOB=**REDACTED**
  NG_CLI_ANALYTICS=**REDACTED**
```

Except, still, angular ng when installing, still asks for the confirmation.

Why? What am I doing wrong?