# Google analytics and CI - update to angular 9

Tags: angular, continuous-integration, circleci

I have a app which is being build on circleCI. 
After upgrading angular from 7 to 9, installing **cli** on circleCI started prompting

```
  Google’s Privacy Policy at https://policies.google.com/privacy? For more details
 and how to change this setting, see http://angular.io/analytics. (y/N)
```

And I cannot choose anything as it's CI. 
I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56355499/stop-angular-cli-asking-for-collecting-analytics-when-i-use-ng-build)  and [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/design/analytics.md), but none of this helped. I tried to Put it in `config.yml` on different ways, but none of them worked. Anyone knows how should I insert the variable?

Here is part of my `config.yml` file:

```
executors:
  node:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:11.6-browsers

    working_directory: ~/repo

commands:
  install_angularcli:
    description: Install angular-cli
    steps:
      - run: sudo npm install -g @angular/cli

jobs:
  build:
    executor: node
    environment:
      - NG_CLI_ANALYTICS: "ci"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't get the environment variable approach to work on circleci. Instead I did the following:

```
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli > /dev/null
```

Which is one of the answers in this post.

[Stop angular cli asking for collecting analytics when I use ng build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56355499/stop-angular-cli-asking-for-collecting-analytics-when-i-use-ng-build/56360325#56360325)

I also needed to upgrade my docker NodeJS version to 10.13 or later (as per the Angular Update Guide).

```
docker:
  - image: circleci/node:10.17
```