# how to provide default value for anlytics to jhipster command?

Tags: jhipster

I am trying to build the jhipster automatically, kindly help me to give a default value to analytics while building the jhipster file.

`jhipster jdl file.jdl --no-insight`

Above command will build and monolith application, after some steps it asks a question for analytics, how do you provide a default value to anlytics in `jhipster` command or `jdl` file ?

### Insights question

[image]

### Analytics question

[image]
I see below options, but I dont see anything for anlytics

```
  -V, --version                           output the version number
  --blueprints <value>                    A comma separated list of one or more generator blueprints to use for the sub generators, e.g. --blueprints kotlin,vuejs
  --force-insight                         Force insight
  --no-insight                            Disable insight
  --force                                 Override every file (default: false)
  --dry-run                               Print conflicts (default: false)
  --whitespace                            Whitespace changes will not trigger conflicts (default: false)
  --bail                                  Fail on first conflict (default: false)
  --skip-regenerate                       Don't regenerate identical files (default: false)
  --skip-yo-resolve                       Ignore .yo-resolve files (default: false)
  -d, --debug                             enable debugger
  -h, --help                              display help for command
```

Comment: It's a question asked by Angular CLI not by JHipster. Have you tried this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56355499/stop-angular-cli-asking-for-collecting-analytics-when-i-use-ng-build

Answer (score 2):

Set an env variable as `export NG_CLI_ANALYTICS=ci` before we run `jhipster jdl app.jdl --no-insight`